# Angular CLI, NativeElement.style - all properties are empty, why?

Tags: angular

I found out that *whenever* I try to `console.log(elementRef.NativeElement.style);`, all properties inside it are empty...

I tried *OnViewInit* and *AfterViewInit*, no luck...

Here is [Stack Blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-euif2k)

The Actual Questions are:

### - Why is it happening?

### - How to set NativeElement.style properties from SCSS or SCC files...?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular doesn't work the same as React.

The styles are not applied inline to the DOM element, but are instead injected into the HTML header as encapsulated styles.

If you have `component.scss`:

```css
:host {
  width: 100%;
}
```

The style is injected into the header as this:

```css
app-example[_ngcontent-c#] {
  width: 100%;
}
```

These styles apply to the instance of the component:

```html
<app-example _ngcontent-c#></app-example>
```

Where Angular sets the attribute `_ngcontent-c#` to match the view encapsulation mode of the component.

This is something that is missing from React, and I don't think there is a comparable way of doing the same thing. The main reason is that Angular is the only framework that has this abstract of a component *view*, and because of this the Angular renderer can encapsulate it.

I hope this answers your question, because it seemed like the kind of thing a React developer would be looking for.

Comment: That's perfect. It's actually what I was looking for. Thanks a lot @Reactgular

Answer (score 0):

There's no error here. You are trying to access the `inline-style` of your angular element.

If you were to add `inline-styles` to the element, you will notice that your code returns a value:

```html
<app-mycomp style="background: blue"></app-mycomp>
```

`private elRef: ElementRef` gives you a reference to the angular component `app-mycomp`.